# Selecting multiple table based on MySQL

Tags: mysql, database

I want to perform a search query on my database tables. This is my tables example.

```
movies
--------------------------
ID (INT) | TITLE (VARCHAR)
--------------------------

actors
-------------------------
ID (INT) | NAME (VARCHAR)
-------------------------

directors
-------------------------
ID (INT) | NAME (VARCHAR)
-------------------------

ma
------------------------------------
ID (INT) | MOVIE (INT) | ACTOR (INT)
------------------------------------

md
---------------------------------------
ID (INT) | MOVIE (INT) | DIRECTOR (INT)
---------------------------------------
```

I want to search on `movies`.`title`, `actors`.`name`, `directors`.`name` based on some keyword. `ma` table have field `movie` that reference to `movie`.`id` and field `actor` that reference to `actor`.`id` and so on. I want to display the result group by `movie`.`id`. The problem is I can't figured out how to perform based on table `directors` and `actors`, based on table `ma` and `md` that have reference to table `movies`. Sorry for the grammar, if you think this question worth it, you can edit it.

So, any idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This one you get everything

```
SELECT m.title, a.name AS actor, d.name AS director 
FROM movies m
INNER JOIN ma ON (ma.movie_id = m.id)
INNER JOIN actors a ON (a.id = ma.actor_id)
INNER JOIN md ON (md.movie_id = m.id)
INNER JOIN directors d ON (d.id = md.director_id)
ORDER BY m.title
```

This one you group by movies

```
SELECT m.title, GROUP_CONCAT(a.name) AS actorS, GROUP_CONCAT(d.name) AS directors
FROM movies m
INNER JOIN ma ON (ma.movie_id = m.id)
INNER JOIN actors a ON (a.id = ma.actor_id)
INNER JOIN md ON (md.movie_id = m.id)
INNER JOIN directors d ON (d.id = md.director_id)
GROUP BY m.id
ORDER BY m.title
```

[EDIT]

For goodness' sake.. just add the WHERE

...
WHERE m.title LIKE 'KEYWORD%' OR a.name LIKE 'KEYWORD%' OR d.name LIKE 'KEYWORD%'

Comment: He has to search some `keyword`...!!

Comment: Yes, I have to search some `keyword` but let me try this one, and will let you know once I finished.

Comment: you don't need to make a comment about that, just remove the columns =/

Comment: how about group_concat only the match field (on actors and directors) and when not match it will give null return?